# Does Windows Phone have any call control options?

Tags: 8.0, calls

A tech blog I read a couple weeks ago did a [comparison between Windows Phone, Android and iOS](http://gizmodo.com/5921789/android-jelly-bean-vs-ios-6-vs-windows-phone-8-the-ultimate-ultimate-comparison). It mentioned that Windows Phone had some limited call control options.

Is this actually the case, or were they stretching the definition of call control to include saving a contact and setting it to a silent ringtone?

Comment: A link to the aforementioned tech blog would be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by call control?

Comment: They didn't go into any detail. For all it matters I could have heard it on the street.

Comment: Call blocking for example.

Comment: Is this the [article](http://gizmodo.com/5921789/android-jelly-bean-vs-ios-6-vs-windows-phone-8-the-ultimate-ultimate-comparison) to which you are referring? (Look under the heading Call Features) Does anyone know if the Do Not Disturb or canned SMS texts are on the books for Windows 8?

Comment: Yeah, that was the one. None of the announcements I've seen talked about any features like that, so I would have to assume they're saying that because it already exists. Alternately they just pulled it out of their ass (it's gizmodo), hence why I said it could have just been some random person on the street saying it.

Comment: @KenCenerelli consider make a real answer with the features of the article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't any call controls in WP 7.5 - which is a shame! The only thing you can do is to set a specific ringtone for a caller via the People hub.